# Make two divs touch without minus CSS properties

Tags: html, css

I am creating a set of "step" divs to show progress through a page and I want these two divs to sit flush against each other but they have a couple pixels between them. I thought `margin` and `padding` 0px would of fixed it but it does nothing.

I would like to achieve this without adding minus properties to the CSS

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aLs2b/)

CSS:

```
.step {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: white;
    border: 1px red solid;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

.line {
    height:1px;
    width:20px;
    background:#717171;
    border-bottom:0px solid #313030;
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="step"></div>
<div class="line"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your markup to this:

```
<div class="step"></div><!--
--><div class="line"></div>
```

As inline-block elements leaves space in between so this might be a hack for the same.

You can see the reference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements) with explanation.

**Or**

You can make it in one line

```
<div class="step"></div><div class="line"></div>
```

### [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/aLs2b/1/)

### [**Demo 2**](http://jsfiddle.net/aLs2b/2/)

Comment: coz there is empty space between div

Answer (score 0):

Write this way http://jsfiddle.net/aLs2b/3/

```
<div class="step"></div><div class="line"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Amit, I appreciate the help but you have wrote exactly the same answer as Dhaval. Please check other answers before posting your own.